# Is there a clicktrackUrl parameter in AFS(Google Adsense For Search ) that can be used?

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, adsense, google-ads-script

I have use to AFS based on the documentation, and I have also reference many other websites. I have found that the clicktrackUrl parameter is used in their code, which can trigger click tracking when clicking on an advertisement. However, I did not see this field in the documentation. The reference documentation is as follows:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9055049

Does this field exist? I added this parameter, but it doesn't work on my website. How can I make this parameter work?

Reference  website, website url: https://www.jnee.uk/us/strategize-g-suite-project-management-system-work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLzG.png)

I want use clicktrackUrl parameter to fixed my tracking problom,thank you

Answer (score 0):

The clicktrackUrl method is not a default method, which is available to all AdSense accounts.

Means: If you want to use it, you will need to be approved for that. You have to contact your account manager at AdSense. If you pass all requirements, it can be activated for your account.